# Isn't i == [i-1] the same thing as i == [i+1] assuming that loop begins at i = 1?

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble understanding why the two scripts below yield different results. Could someone help me understand why these two scripts differ in the way they do?

```js
var str = "this needs to be capped!",
    str1 = str.split(""),
    strarray = [];

for(var i = 1; i < str.length; i++) {
  if(str[i] == " ") {
  strarray.push(str[i]);
  strarray.push(str[i+1].toUpperCase());
  }
  else if(strarray[i] == strarray[i-1]) {
    strarray.push(str[i]);
  } 
}

console.log(strarray.join(','))
```

Output: h,i,s,,N,e,e,d,s,,T,o,,B,e,,C,a,p,p,e,d,!

Vs

```js
var str = "this needs to be capped!",
    str1 = str.split(""),
    strarray = [];

for(var i = 1; i < str.length; i++) {
  if(str[i] == " ") {
    strarray.push(str[i]);
    strarray.push(str[i+1].toUpperCase());
  }
  else if(strarray[i] == strarray[i+1]) {
    strarray.push(str[i]);
  }
}

console.log(strarray.join(','))
```

Output: h,i,s,,N,n,e,e,d,s,T,o,,B,e,,C,a,p,p,e,d,!

In short, the difference here is a lower case 'n.'

Comment: ...why would they be the same?

Comment: How `strarray[i-1]` could be the same as `strarray[i+1]` ??

Comment: I get the same results when I plug them in manually. At any rate, could you help me in explaining the variance of one letter "n" between the two scripts above?

Comment: Run the program in debug mode. You will get to compare each char array comparision. They are not same.

Comment: @Prateek Yes, you are right, they are not the same; however, could you please explain why the second script adds a lower case "n" to my array?

Comment: For most of your iteration strarry[i] & strarry[i+1] are both undefined, so characters get pushed to strarray....bit of a crazy way....

Comment: @StockGod running program in debug mode around the `else if(strarray[i] == strarray[i+1]) {` line as break point will help you understand it. Obviously its wont same as code is different

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you are comparing `undefined` with `undefined`.

For 1st scenario this is what happen

```
    i       str[i]         strarray
   _________________________________
    1       h               [h]
    2       i               [h,i]
    3       s               [h,i,s]
    4       ' '             [h,i,s,,N]
    5       n               [h,i,s,,N]   //here it is comparing undefined=='N' 
                                         //which is false no push in array
    .
    .
```

For 2nd scenario, this is what happens

```
    i       str[i]         strarray
   _________________________________
    1       h               [h]
    2       i               [h,i]
    3       s               [h,i,s]
    4       ' '             [h,i,s,,N]
    5       n               [h,i,s,,N,n]   //here it is comparing undefined==undefined 
                                         //which is true so 'n' was push in array
    .
    .
         /*now whenever space encounters it will push 2 element to
        strarray(space and next character), and for the next i strarray[i] 
        will not be undefined while strarray[i+1] will be undefined so for 
        that i no push into array. */
```

Comment: This does not explain why the same phenomenon as the "n" does not repeat for the other letters.

Comment: @Sébastien hope edit will answer your question not fully but it will give most of the understanding.

Comment: Yes, that is my answer ;) (see below...)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yajiv. You're updated answered helped clear the confusion that I had with your initial response.

Comment: @StockGod I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing positions in a string (immutable) with positions in an array which you keep modifying in a loop.

In your second loop, because you are always looking "ahead" (`strarray[i + 1]`), you are always comparing `undefined` to `undefined`, which is always equal.

In the array, you `push()` the elements so the elements are zero-indexed (whereas your `i` counter starts at 1).

That is the reason why, until you add the first Capital letter, the index is one behind, but not after that (you add 2 elements to the array for every space character).

Which explains why you get an extra "n" (first letter after the first space), and also why that behavior is not replicated after that first instance:

(I omitted the first loop because it is unremarkable)

```js
var str = "this needs to be capped!";
var strarray = [];

for (var i = 1; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str[i] == " ") {
    console.log('space', str[i + 1].toUpperCase());
    strarray.push(str[i]);
    strarray.push(str[i + 1].toUpperCase());
  } else {
    console.log('i: ', i, ' / str[i]: ', str[i], ' / strarray[i]: ', strarray[i], ' / strarray[i + 1]: ', strarray[i + 1], ' / str.length: ', str.length, ' / strarray.length: ', strarray.length);
    if (i > strarray.length) {
      console.log('behind');
    } else {
      console.log('caught up');
    }
    console.log();
    if (strarray[i] == strarray[i + 1]) {
      strarray.push(str[i]);
    }
  }
}
console.log(strarray.join(','));
```

Comment: Awesome dude. I appreciate your incredibly helpful input.